# Clone remote using Arduino with the IRremote library

Tags: arduino, clone

I'm trying to clone an AC remote using Arduino. I read the IR signal using this code:

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;    
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

// Dumps out the decode_results structure.
// Call this after IRrecv::decode()
// void * to work around compiler issue
//void dump(void *v) {
//  decode_results *results = (decode_results *)v
void dump(decode_results *results) {
  int count = results->rawlen;
  if (results->decode_type == UNKNOWN) {
    Serial.print("Unknown encoding: ");
  } else if (results->decode_type == NEC) {
    Serial.print("Decoded NEC: ");
  } else if (results->decode_type == SONY) {
    Serial.print("Decoded SONY: ");
  } else if (results->decode_type == RC5) {
    Serial.print("Decoded RC5: ");
  } else if (results->decode_type == RC6) {
    Serial.print("Decoded RC6: ");
  } else if (results->decode_type == PANASONIC) {   
    Serial.print("Decoded PANASONIC - Address: ");
    Serial.print(results->panasonicAddress,HEX);
    Serial.print(" Value: ");
  } else if (results->decode_type == JVC) {
     Serial.print("Decoded JVC: ");
  }
  Serial.print(results->value, HEX);
  Serial.print(" (");
  Serial.print(results->bits, DEC);
  Serial.println(" bits)");
  Serial.print("Raw (");
  Serial.print(count, DEC);
  Serial.print("): ");
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if ((i % 2) == 1) {
      Serial.print(results->rawbuf[i]*USECPERTICK, DEC);
    } else {
      Serial.print(-(int)results->rawbuf[i]*USECPERTICK, DEC);
    }
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println("");
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    dump(&results);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

And then I use this code to send it to the AC:

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    irsend.sendNEC(0xC64E80C, 32);
    delay(40);
  }
  delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst
}
```

I use 2 separate Arduinos for testing purposes. But somehow even though the hexa value is the same, the content is not sent in the same way.

The IR signal sent using the remote has 108 values and the IR signal from Arduino has only 68 values.

[image: ARDUINO OUTPUT]

I tried to change the remote IR LED with my Arduino IR LED and it works just fine. It's not a hardware problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have done the same thing. I was using this to get the AC codes for the GREE AC. I find it with two weeks struggle and a forum called AnalysIR. If you find any issue in this code below or method let me know.

AC codes are usually long and those doesn't come right with the code which you used above so i am giving you the sample code to run in the Arduino sketch so that you can test.

```
   #define LEDPIN 13
  //you may increase this value on Arduinos with greater than 2k SRAM
  #define maxLen 800

       volatile  unsigned int irBuffer[maxLen]; 
       //stores timings - volatile because changed by ISR
       volatile unsigned int x = 0;
       //Pointer thru irBuffer - volatile because changed by ISR

     void setup() {
     Serial.begin(115200); //change BAUD rate as required
     attachInterrupt(0, rxIR_Interrupt_Handler, CHANGE);
    //set up ISR for receiving IR signal
     }

 void loop() {
   // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

   Serial.println(F("Press the button on the remote now - once only"));
    delay(5000); // pause 5 secs
  if (x) { //if a signal is captured
digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);//visual indicator that signal received
Serial.println();
Serial.print(F("Raw: (")); //dump raw header format - for library
Serial.print((x - 1));
Serial.print(F(") "));
detachInterrupt(0);//stop interrupts & capture until finshed here

for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) { //now dump the times
  if (!(i & 0x1)) Serial.print(F("-"));
  Serial.print(irBuffer[i] - irBuffer[i - 1]);
  Serial.print(F(", "));
                     }

   x = 0;
   Serial.println();
   Serial.println();
   digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);//end of visual indicator, for this time
   attachInterrupt(0, rxIR_Interrupt_Handler, CHANGE);//re-enable ISR for            receiving IR signal
        }

      }

  void rxIR_Interrupt_Handler() {
    if (x > maxLen) return; //ignore if irBuffer is already full
     irBuffer[x++] = micros(); //just continually record the time-stamp of signal transitions

    }
```

Once this is done you will get the right code to send it to the AC.

**A little Tricky part**

once you will receive the codes of raw values you will have to little modify it for example i got the raw values and i converted it into the array.

**What i received for example**
Raw (16): -27750, 4464, 696, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 516, 688, 1620, 692, 512, 692, 1612, 696, 1612, 692, 512, 692, 516, 688, 1616, 696, 1612, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 1612, 692, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 516, 692, 516, 688, 516, 688, 516, 692, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 1620, 688, 516, 688, 520, 684, 1620, 660, 544, 664, 19960, 628, 1680, 628, 1676, 628, 580, 628, 1676, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 628, 584, 620, 576, 628, 580, 628, 576, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 1680, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 1680, 624, 580, 628, 1676, 628, 1680, 628

**To Convert the above raw values into array remove first value which is -27750 and put 3800 instead of that.** Below is the array sample.**

unsigned int data[] = {3800, 4464, 696, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 516, 688, 1620, 692, 512, 692, 1612, 696, 1612, 692, 512, 692, 516, 688, 1616, 696, 1612, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 1612, 692, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 516, 692, 516, 688, 516, 688, 516, 692, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 1620, 688, 516, 688, 520, 684, 1620, 660, 544, 664, 19960, 628, 1680, 628, 1676, 628, 580, 628, 1676, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 628, 584, 620, 576, 628, 580, 628, 576, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 1680, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 1680, 624, 580, 628, 1676, 628, 1680, 628,
};

**Now sending these values to the IR transmitter use this code below.**

```
      #include<IRremote.h>
       IRsend irsend;
       int KHz = 38;                    // default frequency

      unsigned int data[] = {3800, 4464, 696, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 516, 688, 1620, 692, 512, 692, 1612, 696, 1612, 692, 512, 692, 516, 688, 1616, 696, 1612, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 512, 692, 512, 692, 512, 696, 1612, 692, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 516, 692, 516, 688, 516, 688, 516, 692, 1612, 692, 516, 688, 1620, 688, 516, 688, 520, 684, 1620, 660, 544, 664, 19960, 628, 1680, 628, 1676, 628, 580, 628, 1676, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 628, 584, 620, 576, 628, 580, 628, 576, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 1680, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 628, 576, 628, 580, 624, 580, 628, 576, 628, 1680, 624, 580, 628, 1676, 628, 1680, 628,
        };


    void setup() 
   {
     Serial.begin(9600);   
     irsend.enableIROut(38);
   }

    void loop()
   {

    for (int i=0; i<1 ; i++){
    irsend.sendRaw(data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(int),38 ); 
    delay(40);
          }


 }
```